# How to efficiently delete databases and forests?

Tags: marklogic

Is there any efficient method to delete multiples databases w/attached forests in simple operation/query? My local MarkLogic testing machine becoming messy and I would like to rid out all unused databases w/ attached forests at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are handy with postman or curl, you could look at the management rest api, which allows deleting a database with forests with a single DELETE call. For details see:

https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/DELETE/manage/v2/databases/[id-or-name]

HTH!